# Background-color width within a div

Tags: html, css, navbar

My question probably has an easy answer but I can't figure it out.

---

What I am trying to achieve: I am trying to get a small box that will go on the left of a nav button when that page is active its shows a coloured box. My very bad drawing of what I want it to look like :P .

[image].

However I want the box to fit within the div so I don't have to position it myself, but I can change the width to the size I want it to be.

I have tried doing it but I can't find a way to not change the width of the div.

I get that I might have to make it separate from the li tag but I don't want to have to position it.

---

HTML CODE

```
<div class="sidebar">
                <nav id="nav">
                    <h2><?php echo $msg[$lang]["menu"]; ?></h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php" class="active"><i class="fa fa-play" style="padding-right: 19px;"></i> <?php echo $msg[$lang]["mainpage"]; ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="history.php"><i class="fa fa-history" style="padding-right: 19px;"></i><?php echo $msg[$lang]["history"]; ?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="top.php"><i class="fa fa-star" style="padding-right: 19px;"></i><?php echo $msg[$lang]["top"]; ?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Cheers,

-Framework

Answer (score 0):

Just for each of the divs you want colored, add `style="background-color:#cdcdcd"`.

Replace `#cdcdcd` with the HTML color code you want. [Click here for color codes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)

**Edit:**

I realize that I read your question wrong. Try within a div:

```
<div style="background-color:#cdcdcd; width: 20px; height: 100%"></div>
```

**Edit 2:**

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erv0vm9j/)

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question wrong and I edited the answer

Comment: That "height:100%" then changes the height of the whole button. I pretty much want the background to be 5% one colour and 95% the other when that page is active

Comment: That causes this to happen: https://gyazo.com/b5bdc51270b8918cb76f451d4016cefc.png and the text is pulled left

Comment: Can you post your CSS? (I added a JSFiddle to my answer)

Comment: I think I have it sorted mate, that has got me very stuck. Thank you very much for your help though!